# Django validate form based on multiple fields (file fields)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

Is there a way in django to validate a form based on multiple fields. I have seen some examples where people recommend overriding a form's clean method and raising a ValidationError if it fails to meet your custom validation. The problem for me is that I'm not sure you can check whether or not a file was uploaded from within the clean method. I have only been able to access them using the request objects and you do not have access to the request object within the form's clean method.

Answer (score 3):

The method you've described (raising `ValidationError` from within `Form.clean`) is the official way to do [multi-field validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

You can access uploaded files from `self.files` within the `clean` method.  From `django/forms/forms.py`:

```
class BaseForm(StrAndUnicode):
    # This is the main implementation of all the Form logic. Note that this
    # class is different than Form. See the comments by the Form class for more
    # information. Any improvements to the form API should be made to *this*
    # class, not to the Form class.
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, ...):
        self.is_bound = data is not None or files is not None
        self.data = data or {}
        self.files = files or {}
        ...
```